# Maximizing a function that is only defined numerically

Tags: equation-solving, maximize

I have a function of multiple variables that is only defined numerically.  I am trying to maximize the function and find the critical points as fucntions of two parameters p and s using FindRoot but I am only getting complex values.  I can solve the problem analytically when s=1 and there are real interior solutions. I haven't been able to get any real solutions using this method.  Is there another method that would improve my results? The code I am using is below.

```
In[5872]:=
ClearAll["Global`*"]
nh = 400; 
nl = 1200; 
a = 0.3; 
b = 0.4; 
ah = 1; 
al = 1; 
a2 = 1; 
a1 = 1; 
gamma = 0.11; 
Y1 = a1*(b*(ah*nh1)^((s - 1)/s) + (1 - b)*(al*nl1)^((s - 1)/s))^(s/(s - 1)); 
Y2 = a2*(b*(ah*nh2)^((s - 1)/s) + (1 - b)*(al*nl2)^((s - 1)/s))^(s/(s - 1)); 
wh1 = D[Y1, nh1]; 
wl1 = D[Y1, nl1]; 
wh2 = D[Y2, nh2]; 
wl2 = D[Y2, nl2]; 
nl1 = (((1 - tl1)*(1 - th2))^s*nh1*nl)/(((1 - tl1)*(1 - th2))^s*nh1 + 
     ((1 - tl2)*(1 - th1))^s*(nh - nh1)); 
nl2 = nl - nl1; 
nh2 = nh - nh1; 
q1 = (a*Y1)^(1/(1 + p)); 
q2 = (a*Y2)^(1/(1 + p)); 
g1 = (th1*wh1*nh1 + tl1*wl1*nl1)/q1^a; 
g2 = (th2*wh2*nh2 + tl2*wl2*nl2)/q2^a; 
Vh1[nh1_, p_, s_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = g1^gamma*(1 - th1)*(wh1/q1^a); 
Vl1[nh1_, p_, s_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = g1^gamma*(1 - tl1)*(wl1/q1^a); 
Vh2[nh1_, p_, s_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = g2^gamma*(1 - th2)*(wh2/q2^a); 
Vl2[nh1_, p_, s_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = g2^gamma*(1 - tl2)*(wl2/q2^a); 
Wl1[nh1_, p_, s_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = Vl1[nh1, s, th1, tl1, th2, tl2]*nl1; 
Wl2[nh1_, p_, s_, th1_, tl1_, th2_, tl2_] = Vl2[nh1, s, th1, tl1, th2, tl2]*nl2; 
nh1s[p_, s_, (th1_)?NumericQ, (th2_)?NumericQ, (tl1_)?NumericQ, (tl2_)?NumericQ] := 
   nh1 /. FindRoot[Vh1[nh1, p, s, th1, tl1, th2, tl2] - Vh2[nh1, p, s, th1, tl1, th2, 
       tl2], {nh1, 200}, PrecisionGoal -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
     MaxIterations -> 10000]; 
nl1s[p_, s_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = 
   (((1 - tl1)*(1 - th2))^s*nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2]*nl)/
    (((1 - tl1)*(1 - th2))^s*nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2] + 
     ((1 - tl2)*(1 - th1))^s*(nh - nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2])); 
nh2s[p_, s_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = nh - nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2]; 
nl2s[p_, s_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = nl - nl1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2]; 
W1s[p_, s_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = Vl1[nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], p, s, th1, 
     tl1, th2, tl2]*nl1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2]; 
W2s[p_, s_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = Vl2[nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], p, s, th1, 
     tl1, th2, tl2]*nl2s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2]; 
x[p_, s_, th1_, th2_, tl1_, tl2_] = Vh1[nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], p, s, th1, tl1, 
     th2, tl2] - Vl1[nh1s[p, s, th1, th2, tl1, tl2], p, s, th1, tl1, th2, tl2]; 
Sols[p_, s_] := FindRoot[{Derivative[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0][W1s][p, s, th, th, tl, tl] == 0, 
     Derivative[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0][W1s][p, s, th, th, tl, tl] == 0}, 
    {{th, 0.3}, {tl, -0.2}}]; 

In[5909]:=
Sols[1, 1.1]

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
FindRoot::lstol

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
FindRoot::lstol

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
FindRoot::lstol

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
General::stop

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
FindRoot::cvmit

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
FindRoot::cvmit

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
FindRoot::cvmit

During evaluation of In[5909]:=
General::stop

Out[5909]=
{th -> -2.4628622577612025 - 0.39182390250485327*I, 
  tl -> 1.4525847001562655 + 0.23482076297475138*I}
```

Comment: Does NMaximize do what you want?

Comment: I did but I am getting strange solutions. Specifically, I am getting back the same variable values regardless of the parameter values.